# I am having trouble using late return type on a function accepting unpacked varidic template arguments

Tags: c++, templates

I am having trouble using late return type on a function accepting unpacked varidic template arguments. This doesn't compile in Nov CTP Visual Studio.

```
template <typename Function, typename ...Args>
auto invoke ( Function f, Args... args)
    -> decltype(f(args...))
{

    return f(args...);
}

int foo(int x, const char* y = "Hello") {
    cout << x << " : " << y << endl;

    return x;
};

int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[]) {

    auto v = invoke(&foo, 10, "Hello There");
    cout << v << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Did you try using three dots? `decltype(f(args...))`

Comment: Also, normally functions of the sort of `invoke()` tend to perfectly forward the arguments: `auto invoke(Funciton f, Args&&... args) -> decltype(f(std::forward<Args>(args)...))`

Comment: error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type etl::invoke(Function,Args...)'

Comment: Same error with std::forward.

Comment: It is with three dots... My typo edited to reflect the same.

Comment: Can you post the [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)? Adding a simple function, a `main()` and `invoke()`ing the function works with gcc and clang. However, this doesn't might just mean that I ended up using a test case which worked.

Comment: The 2012 CTP for VS is notoriously buggy. Don't trust it without looking behind you. Just move on to VS13, it should be a much better experience.

Comment: The code looks fine, and indeed compiles without warning with both g++ and Clang (once that odd `_tmain()` thing is changed to `main()`). Looks like you've hit a compiler bug.

Comment: Thanks guys. It is indeed a compiler bug = buggy 2012 CTP from MS. My code builds just fine with g++.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone needs it. The following workaround worked for me.

```
template <typename F> struct freturn_type;
template <typename R, typename... A>
struct freturn_type<R (*)(A...)>
{
    typedef R type;
};


template <typename Function, typename ...Args>
typename freturn_type<Function>::type invoke ( Function f, Args... args)
    //-> decltype(f(args...))
{
    return f(args...);
};
```